# How to get driving direction data in iOS6?

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes, direction

I would like to draw a route between 2 points (current location and a selected annotation) from UIMapView.
In iOS versions before 6 , i've used a request to google with lat,long, then received data was decoded and transformed to polyline. All this works as expected.

The same method works on iOS6, but is it a properly (to request google for routing data)?

Can you please share your thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Directions API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits):

> Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited.

Since MapKit in iOS 6 no longer presents a Google map, it seems that it would be a violation of Google's terms of service to use the Google directions API on a MapKit map.  You will either need to find another way of generating driving directions, or find a way to display a Google map in iOS 6 with which you can use Google directions.